# Hive Query with UDF

Tags: encryption, hadoop, hive

I have some encrypted data in an HDFS csv, that I've created a Hive table for, and I want to run a Hive query that first encrypts the query param, then does the lookup.  I have a UDF that does encryption as follows:

```
public class ParamEncrypt extends UDF {

public Text evaluate(String name) throws Exception {

    String result = new String();

    if (name == null) { return null; }

    result = ParamData.encrypt(name);

    return new Text(result);
}
}
```

Then I run the Hive query as:

```
select * from cc_details where first_name = encrypt('Ann');
```

The problem is, it's running encrypt('Ann') across every single record in the table.  I want it do the encryption once, then do the matchup.  I've tried:

```
select * from cc_details where first_name in (select encrypt('Ann') from cc_details limit 1);
```

But Hive doesn't support **IN** or select queries in the where clause.

What can I do?

Can I do something like:

```
select encrypt('Ann') as ann from cc_details where first_name = ann;
```

That also doesn't work because the query parser throws an error saying **ann** is not a known column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it (and actually the way I ended up going with), is by caching the result of the encryption.  It's actually faster this way, because with the join, you get a separate set of map-reduce jobs, which slows down the overall execution time.

it's like this:

```
private static String result = null;

public Text evaluate(String data) {
    if (result ==  null) {
        result = Data.encrypt(data);
    }
    return new Text(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it with a **right outer join** as

```
select * from cc_details ssn_tbl
right outer join ( select encrypt('850-37-8230','ssn') as ssn 
    from cc_details limit 1) ssn_tmp
on (ssn_tbl.ssn = ssn_tmp.ssn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an annotation `@UDFType(deterministic = true)` on your UDF. It's definitely available on the Generic UDFs, you can check if it's available for regular UDF like you have created. If not, just convert your UDF to GenericUDF. You can read about it on [this blog post](http://mark.thegrovers.ca/1/post/2012/06/how-to-write-a-hive-udf.html) that I wrote a while back.